# how to perform addition between database values and users input values as text box values in php

Tags: php

I need to perform an addition of one of the database column's selected values and user input dynamically.
I choose the database values depending on a condition and I fetch it in an array.
Now, I need to sum both values and the result need to placed in another one text box.

I use this code :

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td height="41"><?php echo $res['valuea']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $res['valueb']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $res['valuec']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $res['valued']; ?></td>
            <td><input name="txt" type="text" disabled="disabled" class="txt" id="txt" value="<?php echo $res['valuee']; ?>" readonly="readonly"/></td>
            <td><input class="qty" type="text" id="qty" name="qty" onChange="third();"/></td>
            <td><input class="amount" type="text" name="amount" id="amount"  /></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
} //while
```

I think here is my mistake :

To add the values I used `javascript` but it accepts the first entry only... It doesn't work with the next entries :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function third(){
    var txt=document.getElementById('txt').value;
    var qty=document.getElementById('qty').value;
    var amount=txt*qty;
    document.getElementById('amount').value=amount;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with same id.

Comment: @Rikesh This is actually the answer

Comment: You should also move the `<tbody>` tag out of the loop.

Comment: thank you but it also seems the same answer